IIS Http 404 Error page not getting displayed correctly
Can anyone please suggest from where this error page gets displayed and why?

The default 404 error page configured to be displayed is -

But when we navigate to the url - http://{servername}.com/, it displays the former 404 Not Found Error page.

Could be anything in any of applicationHost.config, machine.config, web.config (for the website) or a separate web.config for a subdirectory or another application-scope. You might have configured IIS to override application-defined 404 responses - or done the opposite and always prefer application-defined 404 responses. The problem might not even lie in IIS: it could be something askew in the HTTP.sys kernel-mode component. Etc. Etc.

Thanks @Dai How to figure out what it is? We have stopped the Default IIS web site then this page displays

By analogy, you're asking which TV channel is responsible for broadcasting static - whereas static is the absense of a TV channel. Similarly, that austere plain white "Not found" page you're seeing is because you disabled IIS's website, so you're (likely) getting a fallback response hardcoded into HTTP.sys. You can't have a custom 404 page unless IIS and its websites are running in the first place.

This error should be caused by misconfigured DNS settings. You may have pointed the domain to an incorrect nameserver or a wrong IP address through an A record. Therefore, you need to check if the domain is pointed correctly to solve this issue.
You should configure the hosts file as below:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx servername

